# Is there a more efficient way to present lots of data than having it all in separate files and activities?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an app in android. It is a reference guide with about 400 items in it. At the minute we have a layout and activity for each item. Is there a more efficient way of presenting this huge amount of data? Each item has different properties to show. There is a list with all the 400 items and each one links to its own activity and layout. Each layout has two scroll views to present the info

Comment: Do you can categorized these items ?

Comment: Unless you explain what the "items" are, how you are rendering them, what their common elements are, and what the differences are, we will have great difficulty helping you.